# Putting a function in a return statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, d3.js, return

I'm making a social network graph that displays information about a writer in a tooltip. However, sometimes some of the data fields in the database I'm working with are empty, so that when you hover over the node it displays nothing (if the field is "") or it displays undefined (if the entire field for that particular writer is deleted). For example `biography: ""`in the dataset returns "Biography: ", and if I delete the biography field for that writer, it returns "Biography: undefined".

I tried to make a function that would return a back-up statement if there's no information in the field or if it's undefined, but (I think) since the function is within a return statement, it doesn't work. It just returns the written out function.

If it turns out that putting a function in a return statement just doesn't work, what are some alternatives I could try (aside from the obvious like fixing the database)? I'm new to programming, so this might be a really obvious mistake.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv48w/

```
//code code code

 bioBackup = function () {
  if (d.biography = undefined || "") { 
    return "There is no listed biography for " + d.name
  } else {
    return d.biography}
  };

//Add the tooltip
  var tip = d3.tip()          
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.name +  
      "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Location:</span>" + " " + d.location + 
      "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Floruit Date:</span>" + " " + d.floruitDate +
      "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Biography:</span>" + " " + bioBackup + 
      '<br>Click through for more information.';
    });

//code code code
```

Comment: Seriously, you're wrong with several things. First, as I said, you somehow ended up with assigning a value in `d.biography` instead of checking it. Second, you should call your `bioBackup` function instead of just stringifying it. Finally, `d` variable should be made known within that function (for example, by passing it as an argument).

Comment: I guess that's what I get for teaching myself with code academy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your jsfiddle link a bit and came up with a solution.

If you replace your tooltip variable code with

```js
var tip = d3.tip()          
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.name +  
    "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Location:</span>" + " " + d.location + 
    "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Floruit Date:</span>" + " " + d.floruitDate +
    "<br><span class='tipTitle'>Biography:</span>" + " " + (d.biography ? d.biography : "There is no listed biography for " + d.name) + 
    '<br>Click through for more information.';
});
```

you can get rid of the `bioBackup` function entirely and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never heard of the ternary operator before.

Comment: @kellyh Yeah, it's a programming operator set that people tend not to tell new people about because it tends to form "bad" code formatting habits and it can be both a blessing when used correctly, and a curse when used incorrectly.